# How to use response parameters in OfBiz screen?

Tags: java, events, screen, response, ofbiz

I wrote my own Java-Event which will be called by a Form which is included by a screen. After entering some parameters into the form fields and submit them, my java event will be called and processes some product analysis. After the analysis there will be an "Analyzer"-Object which holds all the data of the analysis. I put this object in the response and now i wonder how i can use this object in response screens or .ftl files. Anybody any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

have you tries ${parameters.fieldName} in ofbiz?